# Equivalence of two radical equations without certain conditions - correctness of method

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, solution-verification, radical-equations

I have question related to the following example: $\sqrt{22-x} - \sqrt{10-x}=2$.

**First question:**

Do I first need conditions $22-x \geq 0 $ and $ 10-x \geq 0$ to obtain the equivalent equation: $\sqrt{22-x}= \sqrt{10-x}+2$, then take square and so on
or  I don't need these conditions

i.e.$\sqrt{22-x} - \sqrt{10-x}=2$  is already equivalent to $\sqrt{22-x}= \sqrt{10-x}+2$, so we need only $10-x \geq 0$. The right side is non-negative, we take square and so on.

I wonder which method is correct.

**Second question:**

I know from theory that $\sqrt{f(x)}= g(x) \iff g(x) \geq 0 $ and $  f(x)= (g(x))^2 \geq 0$, so condition $f(x)\geq 0$ is automatically fulfilled. Can we do same here i.e. since right side is positive, so is left side in $\sqrt{22-x} - \sqrt{10-x}=2$ and we just take square of both sides?

Please help with this, I am learning for exams and I am confused about this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You should state what exam you're studying for. Approaching this in grade 9 (without complex numbers), would be different than approaching this in university (esp for someone who knows about linear-algebra, which is a tag that you uses, likely incorrectly).

Comment: What is the second option of your first question? You seem to have only asked if one method is ok.

Comment: University exam. I know complex numbers so if you could explain in any way, I would be grateful.

Comment: To clarify: is your 1st question if you need those conditions initially or not?

Comment: I mean the first option where we use conditions $ 22−x≥0$ and $10−x≥0$ , and the second one without conditions

Answer (score 2):

Your argument will be of the form $P_0(x) \implies P_1(x) \implies P_2(x) \implies \cdots$ and, hopefully, you will end up with a set of possible values for $x$, say $x \in D$. Essentially you can now say

$$\text{If $x$ solves $P_0(x)$, then $x \in D$.}$$

This is when you worry about what subset of $D$ will make $P_0(x)$ true.

There is an interesting "trick" that can be used to solve this equation.

\begin{align}
   \sqrt{22-x} - \sqrt{10-x} &= 2 \\
   \sqrt{22-x} + \sqrt{10-x} &= y \\
\hline
   (\sqrt{22-x} - \sqrt{10-x})(\sqrt{22-x} + \sqrt{10-x}) &= 2y \\
   (22-x)-(10-x) &= 2y \\
   12 &= 2y \\
   y &= 6 \\
\hline
   (\sqrt{22-x} - \sqrt{10-x})+(\sqrt{22-x} + \sqrt{10-x}) &= 2+y \\
   2\sqrt{22-x} &= 8\\
   \sqrt{22-x} &= 4 \\
   22-x &= 16 \\
   x &= 6
\end{align}

And a quick check shows that $x=6$ is indeed a solution.

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER TO 1ST QUESTION**

I belive you can just mess around with the terms to find the solutions in $x$ but then you have to check if all of them are valid, ie you do need to use the conditions that $22-x\ge0$ and $10-x\ge0$. Is that helpful?

Comment: I understand that, I tried to rearrange in multiple ways, but what if I choose to do exactly methods that I described in question? Could you please explain which conditions should I use in that case? Do we first have to write conditions $22−x≥0 $ and $10−x≥0$ before transferring terms to right side  i.e. before obtaining $\sqrt(22-x) = \sqrt(10-x) +2$ from the original one?

Comment: @User154 To be honest I don't really understand what you mean by 'use the conditions'. Do you mean to simply state them or to deduce something helpful to your working and solution from them?

Comment: I mean to state them

Comment: @User154 what harm could it do by stating them? However, I'd think you only need to state them at the end when you're rejecting/checking through your solutions.